# My react native site gives multiple mixed content warnings when loading over https using expo google fonts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, google-fonts

I am developing a site that is coded with React Native. I decided to use some Google fonts as they are easy to implement. Everything worked fine until I started using Traefik as a reverse proxy to my site and I decided to make it secure with https. The only problem is that now when it loads it throws 15 **Mixed Content** warnings over insecure fonts.

This is how I'm loading the fonts into my app...

```
import {
    useFonts,
    Pacifico_400Regular,
    ComicNeue_400Regular,
    JosefinSans_400Regular,
    BalsamiqSans_400Regular,
    Inconsolata_400Regular,
} from '@expo-google-fonts/dev';
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';

function BodyText(props) {
    let [fontsLoaded] = useFonts({
        Pacifico_400Regular,
        ComicNeue_400Regular,
        JosefinSans_400Regular,
        BalsamiqSans_400Regular,
        Inconsolata_400Regular,
    });
```

This is the error I'm getting...

*Mixed Content: The page at '' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure font ''. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.*

I'm not sure how to fix this issue as there is no implicit reference to **http** that I can change to **https**.

Edit:

Problem solved thanks to *Emanuele Scarabattoli*

I changed the code above to

```
import { useFonts, Pacifico_400Regular } from '@expo-google-fonts/pacifico';
import { ComicNeue_400Regular } from '@expo-google-fonts/comic-neue';
import { JosefinSans_400Regular } from '@expo-google-fonts/josefin-sans';
import { BalsamiqSans_400Regular } from '@expo-google-fonts/balsamiq-sans';
import { Inconsolata_400Regular } from '@expo-google-fonts/inconsolata';
```

These are the production imports.
Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be related to the `@expo-google-fonts/dev` package itself, in particular to this file:

https://github.com/expo/google-fonts/blob/master/font-packages/dev/index.js

As you can see all the fonts are loaded in `HTTP` and not in `HTTPS`.

You should consider to use the use `@expo-google-fonts/inter` instead:

https://github.com/expo/google-fonts#usage

Or consider to take a look here:

https://docs.expo.io/guides/using-custom-fonts/

Comment: That fixed my problem. Thanks so much for the help!